# How can I prevent a setting in init.el from being overridden during startup?

Tags: init-file, scrolling

Using [emacs-mac-port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port), and I'm trying to configure horizontal scrolling with the trackpad. The following expressions work if I execute them manually via eval-last-sexp,

```
(global-set-key [wheel-right] (lambda ()
                                 (interactive)
                                 (scroll-left 1)))
(global-set-key [wheel-left] (lambda ()
                                (interactive)
                                (scroll-right 1)))
```

but having added them to my init file seems to have no effect. I start up emacs, type a line long enough to be truncated, try to scroll sideways and I have no horizontal scroll. If I open up my init file (~/.emacs.d/init.el) and execute the relevant expressions manually, I DO get horizontal scrolling.

Some investigation shows that at initial startup, wheel-right and wheel-left are both bound to mac-mwheel-scroll, an interactive compiled Lisp function in `Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/term/mac-win.el` which "parses switches controlling interface with Mac window system".

Interestingly, the mac-mwheel-scroll definition includes a comment: `TODO: horizontal scrolling`

How can I give the settings in my init file a higher precedence than what's being set in mac-win.el? I'm guessing mac-win.el is being read later in startup process and thus overriding my settings, but I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: Try hitting `C-h k` before scrolling sideways. This will tell you which function is actually being called.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but there is no reason to quote a lambda form, and every reason not to quote a lambda form.

Comment: Interesting: it's calling mac-mwheel-scroll, in `Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/term/mac-win.el`. I'll update the question.

Comment: I found a copy of `mac-win.el` on the web, it looks like turning off `mac-mouse-wheel-mode` might help?