# mac-mwheel-scroll screws centered-positon-mode when using mouse pad on a macbook laptop

Tags: osx, minor-mode, scrolling, cursor

I am able to scroll using navigation buttons and external mouse on a Mac with this code that keeps the cursor at a specific line at all times.
I am using this code since it is much faster than centered-cursor-mode.

The only problem I am facing is when using the macbook mouse which is mapped to "mac-mwheel-scroll". When using it, the buffer stalls and the cursor doesn't move at all. Any help to figure a solution out is appreciated.

```
(defcustom centered-point-position 0.35
  "Percentage of screen where `centered-point-mode' keeps point."
  :type 'float)

(setq centered-point--preserve-pos nil)

(define-minor-mode centered-point-mode
  "Keep the cursor at `centered-point-position' in the window"
  :lighter " centerpoint"
  (cond (centered-point-mode (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'center-point nil t)
                             (setq centered-point--preserve-pos
                                   scroll-preserve-screen-position)
                             (setq-local scroll-preserve-screen-position 'all))
        (t (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'center-point t)
           (setq-local scroll-preserve-screen-position
                       centered-point--preserve-pos))))


(defun center-point ()
  "Move point to the line at `centered-point-position'."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq (current-buffer) (window-buffer))
    (let ((recenter-positions (list centered-point-position)))
      (recenter-top-bottom))))

(defun centered-point-mode-on ()
  (centered-point-mode 1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-centered-point-mode centered-point-mode
  centered-point-mode-on)
```

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13397/how-can-i-prevent-a-setting-in-init-el-from-being-overridden-during-startup#comment20011_13397), try turning off `mac-mouse-wheel-mode`. Otherwise, I think just rebinding the scroll events to the regular `mwheel-scroll` would probably do the job.

Comment: Disabling mac-mouse-wheel-mode as the comment recommended disabled even the external mouse, which is not the desired outcome.